# How low can the single Merlin engine on the Falcon 9 first stage throttle?

Tags: spacex, reuse, falcon-9, merlin-1d

As I understand it, the Merlin 1D engine on the Falcon 9 that is used to land the first stage, is fairly limited in how low it can throttle.  This makes landing on the barge more difficult -- a suicide burn of sorts.

How low can the engine throttle?

Comment: This was answered in [this question](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8759/can-a-superdraco-engine-help-landing-the-spacex-1st-stage), where @geoffc stated: "Merlin 1D can only throttle down to about 70% and that still generates more thrust (about 100Klbs of thrust)"

Comment: So, that would be a good answer here.  Some references would be nice.  It is a different question though.

Comment: I did not have a reference handy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia and Spaceflight101 both say 70%.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merlin_(rocket_engine_family)#Merlin_1D http://www.spaceflight101.com/falcon-9-v11.html

With the other specs given on the Spaceflight 101 page, this implies close to 2.5:1 TWR at touchdown (~15 m/s<sup>2</sup> deceleration) on an empty tank.

This [tweet from Musk](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/462104679116050432) says "~40%" but if you read the responses to the tweet you'll see that's rather ambiguous. If it could actually reach 40% rated thrust that would be a much less dramatic deceleration in the hover-slam.

Someone with more free time than myself could count pixels and frames in the [CRS-6 landing video](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8766/would-it-have-taken-much-to-steady-spacexs-crs-6-returning-stage-so-it-landed-a) to settle the question (of deceleration rate; you'd need to know the final mass of the stage to get the thrust/throttle figures).

Comment: That makes for a tricky control systems problem.  It would be nice if the coverage of the latest attempt would mention this complication.